# select dinamico

Tags: mysql

boa tarde!

Tenho uma tabela mais ou menos assim:

```
id   |   valor   | nome_campo     |  item_id (fk)
----------------------------------------------
1    |    9      | campo_1        |  22
2    |    10     | campo_2        |  21
3    |    2      | campo_2        |  22
4    |    3      | campo_2        |  21
5    |    3      | campo_1        |  22
6    |    9      | campo_2        |  26
7    |    9      | campo_1        |  22
8    |    9      | campo_3        |  25
9    |    10     | campo_4        |  27
10   |    9      | campo_1        |  24
11   |    10     | campo_2        |  22
12   |    10     | campo_2        |  24
13   |    10     | campo_2        |  22
14   |    10     | campo_1        |  21
```

Preciso listar todos os registros onde:

nome_campo = 'campo_1' e valor = 9

E / OU ????

nome_campo = 'campo_2' e valor = 10

mas que a coluna item_id sejam em comum aos registros retornados com base nas linha acima.

O resultado esperado é este:

```
 
id   |   valor   | nome_campo  |  item_id (fk)
----------------------------------------------
1    |    9      | campo_1     |  22
7    |    9      | campo_1     |  22
11   |    10     | campo_2     |  22
13   |    10     | campo_2     |  22
12   |    10     | campo_2     |  24
10   |    9      | campo_1     |  24
```

Os valores que são passados para a "montagem" do where da query são "campo_1, valor 9 e campo_2, valor 10"

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi certo da pra fazer por esse SQL:

```
select * from tabela where
(
    nome_campo = 'campo_1' AND
    valor = 9
) OR (
    nome_campo = 'campo_2' AND
    valor = 10
);
```

Comment: Respondi na propria pergunta pois não tinha espaço

Answer (score 2):

Solução 1 - Utilizando o operador `IN`:

```
SELECT
    id, valor, nome_campo, item_id
FROM
    tabela
WHERE
    (nome_campo, valor) IN ( ('campo_1',9), ('campo_2',10) );
```

Solução 2 - Utilizando os operadores lógicos `AND` e `OR`

```
SELECT
    id, valor, nome_campo, item_id
FROM
    tabela
WHERE
    (( nome_campo = 'campo_1' AND valor = 9) OR ( nome_campo = 'campo_2' AND valor = 10 ))
```

Comment: Então eu usei das duas maneiras funcionou mas não do jeito que eu queria pois ele traz os dados cujo os valores são iguais a 9 ou igual a 10.

Comment: Respondi na propria pergunta pois não tinha espaço

Answer (score 2):

Tu podes usar este método vai funcionar:

```
select * from tabela where
nome_campo = 'campo_1' AND valor = 9
union all
select * from tabela where
nome_campo = 'campo_2' AND valor = 10
```

Comment: Pode, vai funcionar, mas nem de longe é uma boa resposta.

Comment: Mais não funcionou ele continua me trazendo um ou outro , eu tinha até tentado com union e acabei esquecendo o union all ... mais tambem ainda não é o resultado esperado ... obrigado pela resposta

Comment: usando o union all , exibe aqui o resultado que a Query está trazer ..

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma;

```
declare @tabela  table
(
   id int,
   valor int,
   nome_campo varchar(20), 
   item_id INT  
)

insert into @tabela values
(1,9,'campo_1'  , 22),
(2,10,'campo_2'  , 21),
(3,2,'campo_2'  , 22),
(4,3,'campo_2'  , 21),
(5,3,'campo_1'  , 22),
(6,9,'campo_2'  , 26),
(7,9,'campo_1'  , 22),
(8,9,'campo_3'  , 25),
(9,10,'campo_4'  , 27),
(10,9,'campo_1'  , 24),
(11,10,'campo_2'  , 22),
(12,10,'campo_2'  , 24),
(13,10,'campo_2'  , 22),
(14,10,'campo_1'  , 21)


select * from @tabela
where (valor = 9 and nome_campo = 'campo_1')
or (valor = 10 and nome_campo = 'campo_2')
order by item_id
```

Comment: Respondi na propria pergunta pois não tinha espaço